# SWIFT ToDo app-fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift

```
@IBAction func btnAddTask_Click(sender: UIButton){
    taskMgr.addTask(txtTask.text , desc: txtDesc.text)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    txtTask.text = ""
    txtDesc.text = ""
    self.tabBarController!.selectedIndex = 0
```

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Please help me to found the problem.
Best regards!

Comment: self.tabBarController.selectedIndex is coming up nil. Did you ever give it a value?

Comment: No, Xcode show the problem in line:  taskMgr.addTask(txtTask.text , desc: txtDesc.text)

Comment: Well, something there is returning nil. Figure out which it is. Place a breakpoint there and check.

Comment: Again same problem...I'm stuck!:(

Comment: I know you will have the same problem... But check what is returning nil

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare "taskMgr" as an "Implicitly Unwrapped Optional"? Something like this:

```
let taskMgr: MyTaskManager!
```

In this case it might be that taskMgr is nil at the moment you want to call "addTask" on it. But you can see this easily in the debugger.

[image]

It is very easy. Please look at the screenshot. I have set an breakpoint in viewDidLoad. Then you can open "self" and look at the variables. In my screenshot you can see a searchBar property which is nil. You should check your variables in the same way.

Check the outlet connections of txtTask and txtDesc. Are they maybe nil? And what is with their .text properties? Is there any text in the input fields? Otherwise those properties also could be nil.

Comment: Tnx Darko I will try! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit


var taskMgr: TaskManager = TaskManager ()
struct task
{
    var name = "Un-Named"
    var desc = "Un-Described"
}


class TaskManager: NSObject {

    var tasks = [task  ] ()
    func addTask (name: String, desc: String){
        tasks.append(task(name: name, desc: desc))

    }
}
```